# How to trim a piece of text to full sentences in python

Tags: python

I have a piece of text that is not in full sentences. For example

```
reased 11%. Search advertising revenue, excluding traffic acquisition costs, was relatively unchanged. Indus
```

The full sentences are

```
... increased 11%. Search advertising revenue, excluding traffic acquisition costs, was relatively unchanged. Industry ...
```

What I want is if the sentences is cut, such as the `... increased 11%` and `Industry...`, then I discard them and only return the full sentence `Search advertising revenue, excluding traffic acquisition costs, was relatively unchanged.`

Can I do that with nltk or spacy?

**UPDATE**

Sorry I was not making my question clear in the original post.

There could be different situations:

- `Hey! How are you? Good!` should return `Hey! How are you? Good!`
- `...ey. How are you? I am good. How about....` should return `How are you? I am good.`

I am not aware of the number of full sentences in the text.

Comment: I don't quite understand.. why can't you just `split` by full stops?

Comment: @chaos Yes! You can make use of `spacy` to separate all the sentence

Comment: @user8408080 It's my bad to use this example. A more specified case is such as `I am good. How are you? Thank you.` when all sentences are valid.

Comment: @Comsavvy I am currently reading the doc of `spacy` but couldnt find a method to recognize a `full sentence`. Can you please give some details about which method I should focus on?

Comment: @chaos If the solution I give answers your question, kindly accept it by clicking the ✔ symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the sentences in a string using `spacy` e.g

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("I am good. How are you? Thank you.")
for sent in doc.sents:
    print(sent)
```

The `sents` attribute contains all the sentences in the string.

`Output`:

```
I am good.
How are you?
Thank you.
```

And for the case of using

```
... increased by 11%. Search advertising revenue, excluding traffic acquisition costs, was relatively unchanged. Industry ...
```

and get only the full sentence, you can simply place `doc.sents` in the `list()` method and make use of the index to access it. e.g

```py
doc = nlp("... increased 11%. Search advertising revenue, excluding traffic acquisition costs, was relatively unchanged. Industry ...")
print(list(doc.sents)[1])
```

Output:

```
Search advertising revenue, excluding traffic acquisition costs, was relatively unchanged.
```

Comment: @chaos If this answers your question, kindly accept it by clicking the ✔ symbol.

Comment: Many thanks to your response. But I don't know how the text is gonna look like. It might be the case that all sentences are valid or the case when only a few of them are valid. Do I have a way to distinguish that?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you just said? I mean the invalid sentence.

Comment: `ey. How are you? I am good. How about`  In this piece of text only `How are you? I am good.` should be returned as they are full sentences. Both `ey.` and `How about` should be discarded as they are not valid sentences. I don't know how many full sentences the text has.

Comment: I think you will find the article useful [Spacy in Python by RealPython](https://realpython.com/natural-language-processing-spacy-python/)